# Internet Explorer DNS, Cache

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-cache

I was hoping someone may be able to help me out with a specific IE issue as I'm unable to replicate it with VMWare.

I recently changed an IP address of a site that I host. In the short time while I was getting the DNS records updated the client viewed the website using Internet Explorer. The server responded with its standard "Website misconfiguration issue, possibly because the IP changed." (that's the short version)

The DNS was updated, the site is again showing correctly, however the client is still seeing the error message.

What I have done:

- Asked them to hit F5
- Clear browser cache
- Ipconfig /flushdns
- I asked them to ping the domain and it responds back with the new IP address.
- Access the site via IP - can see the new site.
- Click on a menu item and they can go to any page, but when they go to the homepage the "error page appears again"

I'm at a loss at the moment.

Comment: How sure are you that they obeyed your instructions?  I mean, there are people who might think that `F5` means `f` then `5` ...

Comment: Yeah mate, I was on the phone and explained to them it was the F5 key at the top of the keyboard.

Comment: Do they have a proxy between them and you?  That's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: I will check it out, to cross my t's and dot i's. Im pretty sure they are just on a ADSL modem/router setup.

Comment: There could also be weird browser toolbars doing caching or something strange like that, but it's hard to imagine much else.  This is the kind of weird thing you usually have to see for yourself.  I take it you can't just remote in?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that.. But I think I may have to. Its good to know that I wasnt going crazy and overlooking something simple. Though I can imagine, Ill remote in and bam it works.. Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this info helps other people.

I cant explain why this works, but it did.

IE9 has an inPrivate Browsing option. I simply turned that on browsed to the webpage and I could see the homepage. Close the private browser down, and was able to view the site as per normal.

Comment: Interesting but weird! `Ipconfig /flushdns` should have done the trick. Does clearing the browser's cache also clears the DNS entries it holds inside it? If I'm not wrong a browser's DNS cache is different from a computer's DNS cache.

Comment: At least google chrome has an explicit way to clear the DNS host entires as described here http://www.howtogeek.com/197804/how-to-clear-the-google-chrome-dns-cache-on-windows/. Clearing the whole browsing history and other things might be painful at times just to clear the DNS cache of the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Internet explorer has another internal DNS cache which stores the DNS entries for 30 minutes.

After flushing the DNS of the computer, you may either close the browser to reset the internal cache of Internet Explorer, or wait for 30 minutes.

For details: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/263558/how-internet-explorer-uses-the-cache-for-dns-host-entries